# Issues with installation of node.js application - ReferenceError: primordials is not defined after execution of gulp command

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I tried to install the node.js application from this Github repository:https://github.com/jsprodotcom/sentimentAnalysisApp

I downloaded all the compressed file, decompressed under my Desktop folder on Windows 10 laptop with installed Node.js 14.17.5 LTS version, copied my API keys of my Twitter account into twitter.js file, and executed the command from cmd prompt "npm install".

Then I tried to execute the command "gulp" in order to activate the server gulp to connect to the HTML page http://localhost:3000 but I got this type of error:

ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
at fs.js:45:5
at req_ (C:\Users\Filippo\Desktop\sentimentAnalysisApp-master\node_modules\natives\index.js:143:24)
at Object.req [as require] (C:\Users\Filippo\Desktop\sentimentAnalysisApp-master\node_modules\natives\index.js:55:10)
at Object. (C:\Users\Filippo\Desktop\sentimentAnalysisApp-master\node_modules\gulp-watch\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:1:37)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)

Into the folder "node-modules" of the Githubrepository, once downloaded and decompressed, you find the js files into there are the errors reported by node.js (for example \node_modules\natives\index.js).

Anyone can help me to solve these issues in order to execute correctly the application by connecting to the page http://localhost:3000 with my Edge or Chrome browser on my laptop?

Thanks in advance for the collaboration

Answer (score 0):

You might have solved this by now. This sentiment analysis app is a 7 year old code base and you will need to run it with an old version of node. Try v10.24.1 LTS and then it should work.